# Появляется ошибка на локальном сервере Openserver: Fatal error: Class 'testsite\base\Controller' not found in D:\Openserver

Tags: php

Появляется ошибка на локальном сервере Openserver:

`Fatal error: Class 'testsite\base\Controller' not found in D:\Openserver\OSPanel\domains\testsite.ru\app\controllers\AppController.php on line 11`

**Вот здесь класс:**

```
<?php

namespace testsite\base;

abstract class Controller{

    public $route;
    public $controller;
    public $model;
    public $view;
    public $prefix;
    public $layout;
    public $data = [];
    public $meta = ['title' => '', 'desc' => '', 'keywords' => ''];

    public function __construct($route){
        $this->route = $route;
        $this->controller = $route['controller'];
        $this->model = $route['controller'];
        $this->view = $route['action'];
        $this->prefix = $route['prefix'];
    }

    public function getView(){
        $viewObject = new View($this->route, $this->layout, $this->view, $this->meta);
        $viewObject->render($this->data);
    }

    public function set($data){
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function setMeta($title = '', $desc = '', $keywords = ''){
        $this->meta['title'] = h($title);
        $this->meta['desc'] = h($desc);
        $this->meta['keywords'] = h($keywords);
    }

    public function isAjax() {
        return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] === 'XMLHttpRequest';
    }

    public function loadView($view, $vars = []){
        extract($vars);
        require APP . "/views/{$this->prefix}{$this->controller}/{$view}.php";
        die;
    }

}
```

**Вот здесь файл куда надо подключить класс Contoller**

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use app\models\AppModel;
use app\widgets\currency\Currency;
use testsite\App;
use testsite\base\Controller;
use testsite\Cache;

class AppController extends Controller{

    public function __construct($route){
        parent::__construct($route);
        new AppModel();
        App::$app->setProperty('currencies', Currency::getCurrencies());
        App::$app->setProperty('currency', Currency::getCurrency(App::$app->getProperty('currencies')));
        App::$app->setProperty('cats', self::cacheCategory());
    }

    public static function cacheCategory(){
        $cache = Cache::instance();
        $cats = $cache->get('cats');
        if(!$cats){
            $cats = \R::getAssoc("SELECT * FROM category");
            $cache->set('cats', $cats);
        }
        return $cats;
    }

}
```

Кто покажет как исправить эту "детскую" ошибку?
Пробовал разные варианты.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: где класс? ...либо автолоадер сломан, либо класс не так назван как нужно, либо его нет по указанному пути

Comment: Если вы используете [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) автозагрузчик (например автозагрузчик композера), то файл с классом `testsite\base\Controller` должен быть в файле `D:\Openserver\OSPanel\domains\testsite.ru\testsite\base\Controller.php`. Указите какой автозагрузчик вы используете и в каких файлах находятся ваши классы.

Comment: PSR-4 используется да.

Comment: Тут дело в том что переименовывался рабочий сайт.То есть все папки ,файлы,текст в файлах с именем нового домена с помощью блокнота nootpad++ переименовывался.Но после этого постоянно появлялись ошибки что тот или иной класс не находятся.

Comment: Может надо было не просто переименовывать рабочий сайт,а запускать скажем автозагрузчик с консоли ,а не просто скопировать  и поменять названия? Не пойму почему ошибки возникают .
Как тогда переименовать рабочий сайт в openserver-e чтобы сайт с новым именем заработал ?

Одно ясно что одного переименования недостаточно выходит.

Comment: Всё произошло при изменении названия сайта.Менялся не только домен но и это имя в файлах,папке - в общем везде где встречается с помощью блокнота notepad++

Может надо было файлы старого сайта на просто копировать и переименовывать но еще что-то делать с  ним ? Может файлы что пришли по автозагрузчику надо было с командной строки запускать ,а не просто копировать в сайт уже готовые ?

А после переименования всегда появлялись сообщения что тот или иной класс не найден в таком то файле.

Что делать ,как правильно переименовывать сайт ?
Ведь он до этого работал.

Comment: Мало того если уже переименованный нерабочий сайт если снова переименовать в старый то он замечательно работает.

Comment: чтобы переименовать сайт - достаточно было изменить название каталога где он лежит. всё. и перезапустить OpenServer.......... При переименовании всего и вся надо в консоли у сайта сделать `composer dump-autoload`, чтобы автозагрузчик пересобрал  зависимости со всеми новыми путями

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`testsite` данная папка в корне или это и есть корень проекта? Корень прописан в сomposer.json?

По ошибке видно то, что автозагрузчик не может найти класс, это может быть по двум причинам, первая: у вас попросту нет данного файла\класса, но раз уж он у вас создан, то ошибка явно в иерархии директорий и файлов.

Попробуйте добавить в composer.json следующее:

```json
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Testsite\\": "testsite/",
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
```

При этом, папка `testsite` с вашим классом должна находиться в корне проекта, в классе, в котором вы будете использовать данный класс необходимо указывать Testsite с большой буквы согласно правилам PSR.

К примеру `use Testsite\myclass`

[если мой ответ вам помог, то проголосуйте за него и нажмите на галочку справа у ответа]

Comment: D:\Openserver\OSPanel\domains\testsite.ru\vendor\testsite\core

Comment: В composer.json прописано следующее:
`{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "testsite\\": "vendor/testsite/core",
      "app\\": "app"
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "gabordemooij/redbean": "dev-master",
    "vlucas/valitron": "^1.4",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "^5.4"
  }
}
`